# why "adContent" class name is not working in css

Tags: css, html, class

```css
.adContent {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.adContent>p {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="adContent">
  <p>this is the testing content</p>
</div>
```

but if i remove "ad" from the class name, then it'll work.

like this `class="Content"`

What rookie mistake am I making now?

Comment: It's working. https://jsfiddle.net/p87ssyrL/5/

Comment: The code works fine as @ketan have told you. Try to clean cache from your navigator.

Comment: ctrl+f5 to load page with "new" styles

Comment: yup it's working..the "ad" word is blocked by adblocker..so don't use ad word in class name if your using adblocker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you probably have **AdBlocker** installed in your browser. The keyword `ad` is conventionally used with banner ads and other ads on a webpage. The AdBlocker hence dynamically hides such `div`, as you rightfully expect them to. Hence it would be smart to avoid using such class/id names.

**It is not imposed by nor is not a limitation of CSS or HTML.**

Pause the AdBlocker and try again.
Thanks. I learned something. :)

Comment: ohh that means if i'm using "ad" word in class name, then it'll blocked by AdBlocker.. i just turn off my adblocker then it's working fine..

Comment: How exactly each AdBlocker works we'll have to check to know. But yeah, try and avoid them, as lots of people have AdBlockers installed. Please mark as the right answer if this helped you. Thanks.